# Function in C not returning correct data after I include another function

Tags: c

I am writing a program that creates an array of ten integers. I have to define max 10 constant and use functions.getdata(ask user for numbers),displaydata(display)
displaylargest,smallest,average,range,and median.

I am stuck on average because soon as I added that function my largest displays a weird number but if I comment out the average function my largest displays correct answer. Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

int getdata(int array[]);
int displaylargest(int array[]);
int displaysmallest(int array[]);
int displayaverage(int array[]);

void displaydata(int array[]);

int main () {
    int array[MAX];
    int largest;
    int smallest;
    int average;
    printf("\nEnter ten numbers \n\n");
    getdata(array);
    displaydata(array );
    largest=displaylargest( array);
    printf("\nThe  largest %d\n", largest);
    smallest=displaysmallest( array);
    printf("\nThe smallest is %d\n", smallest);
    average=displayaverage(array);
    printf("\nThe average is %d\n", average);
    return 0;
}

int getdata(int array[]) {
    int x;
    printf ("Enter a number\n ",x+1);
    for(x=0;x<MAX;x++)
        scanf ("%d",&array[x]); 
}

int displaylargest(int array[]) {
    int x, largest=array[x];
    for (x=0; x<MAX; x++) {
        if (array[x]>largest)
            largest=array[x];
    }
    return(largest);
}

int displaysmallest(int array[]) {
    int x, smallest=array[x];
    for (x=0; x<MAX; x++) {
        if (array[x]<smallest)
            smallest=array[x];
    }
    return(smallest);
}

int displayaverage(int array[]) {
    int x;
    int sum=0;
    int average;

    for (x=0; x<MAX; x++) {
        sum+=array[x];
    }
    {
        average=sum/MAX;    
    }
    return(average);
}

void displaydata(int array[]) {
    int x;
    for(x=0; x<MAX; x++) {
        printf("%d, ",array[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `int x, largest=array[x];` , this is undefined behavior since `x` isn't initialized. You're initializing `largest` to whatever junk is at `array[x]`, which depends on whatever junk `x` is. Same problem in `displaysmallest`

Comment: `int x, largest=array[x];` --> `int x, largest=array[0];`

Comment: You declared `getdata` as returning an `int` but you don't return anything from that function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize local variables in your functions especially when you are using that to access your array. Without that local variable can contain any value ,if you use that as index to your array, you might be accessing valid memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10

void getdata(int array[]);
int displaylargest(int array[]);
int displaysmallest(int array[]);
int displayaverage(int array[]);

void displaydata(int array[]);

int main() {
    int array[MAX];
    int largest;
    int smallest;
    int average;

    printf("\nEnter ten numbers \n\n");
    getdata(array);
    displaydata(array);
    largest = displaylargest(array);
    printf("\nThe  largest %d\n", largest);
    smallest = displaysmallest(array);
    printf("\nThe smallest is %d\n", smallest);
    average = displayaverage(array);
    printf("\nThe average is %d\n", average);

    return 0;
}

void getdata(int array[]) {
    int x;
    printf("Enter a number\n " );
    for (x = 0; x<MAX; x++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[x]);
    }
}

int displaylargest(int array[]) {
    int x, largest = array[0];
    for (x = 0; x<MAX; x++) {
        if (array[x]>largest)
            largest = array[x];
        }
    return(largest);
}

int displaysmallest(int array[]) {
    int x, smallest = array[0];
    for (x = 0; x<MAX; x++) {
        if (array[x]<smallest)
            smallest = array[x];
    }
    return(smallest);
}

int displayaverage(int array[]) {
     int x;
     int sum = 0;
     int average;

     for (x = 0; x<MAX; x++) {
        sum += array[x];
      }
      {
        average = sum / MAX;
     }
     return(average);
 }

void displaydata(int array[]) {
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x<MAX; x++) {
        printf("%d, ", array[x]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In c if we have local variable without initialization ,then it will have some garbage value. And in many of the functions u are intializing somevalue = array(x) it is not correct. The location you are accessing on the array is not valid.Make those chages it will work correctlu

Answer (score 0):

Local variables need to be used here. While defining

> largest=array[x];

make sure that x=0, else x may contain garbage value and the array may try to access invalid memory locations, leading to either the conditions known as underflow or overflow.

Also, I see that you've declared getdata() of type int, though it is not returning any value. Please make it of type void, as is just used to insert the asked values into the array. Hope this helps!